# How to make google chrome only for internal use?

Tags: google-chrome

I wanna make google chrome only for internal use in our company, no external access to internet, is this passible? or only make chrome to access one cooperation site, no other site can be accessed.

we need to use IE10 to access internet, chrome to access outlook web app (web based email access)

I know there is kiosk mode, but it is a full screen and if there is a outside link on page, chrome can still go outside of our network, is there a way to block outgoing traffic?

Comment: Sounds like another braindead corporate policy. Pain without a gain.

Comment: That does indeed seem bass ackwards. There's almost certainly no point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want Chrome for internal use only but IE for everything else then block the Chrome application at your corporate firewall.  Depending on the firewall or other security measures you have installed you should be able to selectively block applications from getting outside the network.

I know in Windows 7 and I believe in most other commercial firewall applications you can select block all connections from this application.  It depends a lot on your network topology as well.  As long as everything is inside the gateway this should be a simple matter of not allowing it through the gateway.

Comment: You can't block "Chrome" from accessing the internet since any traffic would appear exactly like it does when IE is used.

Comment: "Next-Gen" firewalls will do this.  [Sophos](http://www.sophos.com/en-us.aspx) and [Barracuda](https://www.barracuda.com/products/webfilter/features) both have the ability to apply filters to restrict both web applications and user applications depending on specific rulesets.

Answer (score 1):

The only way an edge firewall is going to be able to identity which browser is sending traffic is by the user agent string. Since all the major browsers provide features to change their UA strings, the answer to your question is "you can't".

A locally installed firewall product may be able to restrict traffic based on the executable. The Firewall with Advanced Security feature included with Windows can create an Outbound Traffic rule which restricts the destination by ip address. Such a rule could be applied to many machines at once using Group Policy (assuming an Active Diretory forest).

Seriously, though, Why do you want to block Chrome? What about Firefox? Opera? Lynx? Iron? Other web browsers? Are you going to create rules for all of those?

Answer (score 0):

No.  Since Chrome uses IE's settings there are no changes you can make that would make Chrome just intranet and IE internet.

If you were to use Firefox instead it would be possible to set up a proxy and route the traffic through the proxy in Firefox and not in IE so the internet is available in IE and not in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You can set Chrome to run through an internal proxy which only allows traffic to the OWA site. Normally, Chrome uses the same proxy settings as IE - which would mean you'd have to do [user agent sniffing in your proxy rules](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/acl/) to allow IE past but keep Chrome blocked - but you can use a [command line switch to override Chrome's proxy](http://www.addictivetips.com/internet-tips/google-chrome-proxy-server-settings/).

Note this isn't 100% foolproof (what is?) - end users may still be able to bypass the proxy by launching Chrome directly (if you use option #2) or spoofing user agents (option #1).